# Test three-way correlation

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I'm working on Gaze in Turns in conversation. The kind of data is illustrated here:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Gaze_dur = c(25,35,75,55,
               150,120,170,190),
  N_p = c(3,3,3,3,
          2,2,2,2),
  Turn_dur = c(100,120,150,110,
               200,230,210,250)
)
```

I know that Turns in Dyads (2 ppl talking) are on average longer than Turns in Triads (3 ppl talking). I also know that Gaze durations are longer in Dyads than in Triads:

```
df %>%
  group_by(N_p) %>%
  summarise(Turn_dur_mean = mean(Turn_dur),
            Gaze_dur_mean = mean(Gaze_dur))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    N_p Turn_dur_mean Gaze_dur_mean
  <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1     2          222.         158. 
2     3          120           47.5
```

How can I test the hypothesis that ***Gazes* are shorter in Triads than Dyads because *Turns* are shorter in Triads than Dyads**?

I would think that one step forward toward answering that question might be by computing the **porportional duration** of `Gaze_dur` against `Turn_dur`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Gaze_dur_prop = Gaze_dur / Turn_dur)
  Gaze_dur N_p Turn_dur Gaze_dur_prop
1       25   3      100     0.2500000
2       35   3      120     0.2916667
3       75   3      150     0.5000000
4       55   3      110     0.5000000
5      150   2      200     0.7500000
6      120   2      230     0.5217391
7      170   2      210     0.8095238
8      190   2      250     0.7600000
```

But to proceed from there (if that's the right first step at all)? What's the appropriate statistical test?

Comment: How would this work in the present case?

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions between Stack Exchange sites. This question is not really about programming specifically, but much more about statistical analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a [mediation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_(statistics)) question to me — you want to test whether the effect of `N_p` on `Gaze_dur` is mediated by `Turn_dur`. I would use lavaan to test this as a path model.

```
library(lavaan)

model <- ' # direct effect
             Gaze_dur ~ c*N_p
           # mediator
             Turn_dur ~ a*N_p
             Gaze_dur ~ b*Turn_dur
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
fit <- sem(model, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

```
lavaan 0.6-12 ended normally after 1 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                         5

  Number of observations                             8

Model Test User Model:
                                                      
  Test statistic                                 0.000
  Degrees of freedom                                 0

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                             Standard
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Gaze_dur ~                                          
    N_p        (c)  -44.935   39.414   -1.140    0.254
  Turn_dur ~                                          
    N_p        (a) -102.500   13.405   -7.647    0.000
  Gaze_dur ~                                          
    Turn_dur   (b)    0.635    0.361    1.760    0.078

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .Gaze_dur        373.940  186.970    2.000    0.046
   .Turn_dur        359.375  179.687    2.000    0.046

Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    ab              -65.065   37.933   -1.715    0.086
    total          -110.000   16.105   -6.830    0.000
```

To walk through the output:

**`Regressions`**

- `Gaze_dur ~ N_p  (c)`: *direct effect* or *c' path.* This the effect of X (`N_p`) on Y (`Gaze_dur`) that *isn't* attributable to the mediator M (`Turn_dur`).
- `Turn_dur ~ N_p  (a)`: *a path.* Effect of X (`N_p`) on M (`Turn_dur`).
- `Gaze_dur ~ Turn_dur  (b)`: *b path.* Effect of M (`Turn_dur`) on Y (`Gaze_dur`).

**`Variances`**

- These show the estimated residual variance of Y and M that aren't explained by X.

**`Defined Parameters`**

- `ab`: *indirect effect.* Effect of X (`N_p`) on Y (`Gaze_dur`) "through" or "explained by" M (`Turn_dur`). **This is the key effect for testing mediation.**
- `total`: *total effect* or *c path.* Effect of X (`N_p`) on Y (`Gaze_dur`), including both the direct and indirect effects. In other words, the effect of X on Y without controlling for M.

So in this toy data, there’s suggestive evidence of mediation, since the indirect effect (`ab`) is trend-significant.

NB, traditionally you would call this "complete" (as opposed to "partial") mediation, since the `total` effect of `N_p` on `Gaze_dur` is significant, while the direct effect (`Gaze_dur ~ N_p  (c)`) isn't. But distinguishing "complete" from "partial" mediation based on *p* values is increasingly frowned upon and considered arbitrary.

Comment: Wow - super impressive. Would there be any nice way of visualizing the (results of the) model?

Comment: In applying this model to my actual data I get this Warning: `Warning messages:
1: In lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  :
  lavaan WARNING: some observed variances are larger than 1000000
  lavaan NOTE: use varTable(fit) to investigate
2: In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Could not compute standard errors! The information matrix could
    not be inverted. This may be a symptom that the model is not
    identified.`

Comment: Large variances can happen when your variables are of very different magnitudes, which yours are. I would try rescaling your data (`as.data.frame(scale(df))` if it's just those three variables). Or scaling `Gaze_dur` and `Turn_dur`, and changing `N_p` to a factor.

Comment: As for how to visualize, the classic way is through a path diagram, which you can [make in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46465752/17303805) or [with other tools](https://app.diagrams.net/). You could also show relationships among all three variables in a gridded plot [like this](https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/_images/pymc-examples_examples_case_studies_mediation_analysis_5_1.png).

Comment: Thanks so much! After rescaling the code works fine. It's just hard for me to make sense of the result. How would you interpret this output:  PART 1: 
`Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  aoi_dur ~                                           
    N_p        (c)   -0.139    0.007  -20.271    0.000
  Duration ~                                          
    N_p        (a)   -0.037    0.007   -5.400    0.000
  aoi_dur ~                                           
    Duration   (b)    0.067    0.007    9.772    0.000`

Comment: PART 2: 
`Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .aoi_dur           0.975    0.010  101.978    0.000
   .Duration          0.999    0.010  101.978    0.000
Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    ab               -0.003    0.001   -4.726    0.000
    total            -0.141    0.007  -20.604    0.000`

Comment: I've edited my answer with more explanation of the output. As I explain there, the key test would be after the `Variances` table, in the `ab` line under `Defined Parameters`. Otherwise, the `Regressions` table is telling you that all three variables are interrelated, and, since the direct effect `aoi_dur ~ N_p` is significant, that the effect of `N_p` on `aoi_dur` isn't *entirely* accounted for by `Duration`. Whether it's partially accounted for depends on the result for `ab`.

Comment: Just posted a new question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598051/seeking-help-in-interpreting-the-summary-of-a-mediation-model and would be super grateful if you could take a look and provide some insight