# Seeking help in interpreting the summary of a mediation model

Tags: r, mediation

This is a follow-up question to [Test three-way correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/597336/test-three-way-correlation/597337).
I'm working on gaze data in triadic interaction. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
df
# A tibble: 9,860 × 3
   Duration aoi_dur Gaze_alt
      <dbl>   <int>    <int>
 1     1703    1039        0
 2     1703     498        0
 3     2010     310        0
 4     2010     105        0
 5     2010     205        0
 6     2010     635        0
 7     2051      88        0
 8     2051     303        0
 9     3798    1187        1
10     3798     132        1
# … with 9,850 more rows
```

I want to test the notion that the duration of a gaze (stored in column `aoi_dur`) depends on whether or not there is Gaze Alternation (a binary variable called `Gaze_alt`) but that relationship is *mediated* by a third variable, namely the duration of the speaking turn in which the gazes occur (this variable is called `Duration`). As noted by an answer to my previous question, this scenario calls for **mediation analysis**.

Since I'm new to mediation analysis, I have difficulty understanding the model output and would be grateful for advice on how to 'read' it:

After rescaling the mediation model looks like this:

```
# rescale:
df_0 <- as.data.frame(scale(df))

# model:
model <- ' # direct effect
             aoi_dur ~ c*Gaze_alt
           # mediator
             Duration ~ a*Gaze_alt
             aoi_dur ~ b*Duration
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '
fit <- sem(model, data = df_0)
summary(fit)
```

And the (abbreviated) summary is this:

```
Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  aoi_dur ~                                           
    Gaze_alt   (c)    0.007    0.010    0.695    0.487
  Duration ~                                          
    Gaze_alt   (a)    0.254    0.010   26.086    0.000
  aoi_dur ~                                           
    Duration   (b)    0.080    0.010    7.670    0.000

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .aoi_dur           0.993    0.014   70.214    0.000
   .Duration          0.935    0.013   70.214    0.000

Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    ab                0.020    0.003    7.359    0.000
    total             0.027    0.010    2.726    0.006
```

So, what does this summary say with regard to the question whether and to what extent there is a significant relationship between `aoi_dur` and `Gaze_alt` and whether or to what extent that relationship is mediated by `Duration`? Help with this interpretive task is very much appreciated!

**NB:**

Unfortunately, there is not enough space to post the full data set and since I'm seeking help interpreting the output of the mediation model for the full data set, posting a smallish sample does not make sense - apologies!

Comment: You can post a link to the data set!

Comment: How is that done?

Comment: The short answer is that there is a relationship between `aoi_dur` and `Gaze_alt` (`total` effect, *B* = 0.027, *p* < .01), and this relationship is mediated by `Duration` (`ab` effect, *B* = 0.020, *p* < .001).